# .save() method not updating data in database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, mongoose

I want to mark a as turf booked or not using put request. I am unable to update the data. I am using .save() method to update the data.

```
app.put("/turf/:turfId/day/:dayIndex/time-slot/:timeSlotId", async (req, res) => {
  const tid = parseInt(req.params.turfId);
  const dayIndex = parseInt(req.params.dayIndex);
  const timeSlotId = parseInt(req.params.timeSlotId);
  const booked = req.body.booked;

  const turf = await turfData.findOne({ turfId: tid });
  if (!turf) {
    res.status(404).send("Turf not found");
    return;
  }
  const day = turf.days[dayIndex];
  if (!day) {
    res.status(404).send("Day not found");
    return;
  }
  const timeSlot = day.timeSlots.find((t) => t.id === timeSlotId);
  if (!timeSlot) {
    res.status(404).send("Time slot not found");
    return;
  }
  timeSlot.booked = booked; 
  
  await turf.save();
  res.send(turf);
});
```

[image]

I am getting response 200 OK on thunder client but I dont know why it is not getting updated in monogoDB.

[image]

Someone who might have gone through similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are saving the *turf* but to save it in the DB, you have to create it too.

```
const createTurf = new turfData({
    // data to be saved
})
await createTurf.save()
```

You can try this.